# .NET datarow visualizer?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2008, visualizer

Are there any datarow visualizers which work in VS 2008? I have tried a couple (DotNetDan & Captator) and they both give cast exceptions. It seems these were developed for VS 2005.

I know I can put a datarow in a datatable and view it through a datatable visualizer but I don't want to write code every time I want to inspect one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Captator updated their visualizer which you can get from:
http://captator.dk/captator.aspx?article=165

Answer (score 0):

[Righthand Dataset Debugger Visualizer](http://cs.rthand.com/blogs/blog_with_righthand/pages/Righthand-Dataset-Debugger-Visualizer.aspx)

Comment: it doesn't do datarows. it doesn't do DataTables either. Nice GUI though.